# How do I fix a "no module named websocket" error?

Tags: python, websocket

I installed a websocket client using `pip3 install websocket_client`, I also installed `pip3 install websocket`. when i do pip list it shows that i have both of these packages installed. When I run my code, however, i receive an error that says no module named websocket. When I try to change the import name to websocket-client i receive a syntax error. i am working in a venv and i copied my code below:

```
import websocket

socket = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')

ws = websocket.websocketapp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

The error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/rushishelat/quant/venv/bot.py
(base) Veds-MacBook-Pro-2:quant rushishelat$ /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/rushishelat/quant/venv/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rushishelat/quant/venv/bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import websocket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'
(base) Veds-MacBook-Pro-2:quant rushishelat$
```

Comment: it is `pip3 install websocket-client` not `pip3 install websocket_client`

Comment: You may have more than one python installed. Try `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip list` to see if websocket is in that python's packages.

Comment: environment `(base)` looks like you are using anaconda unless you named your venv to be base? so ..are you using anaconda ? did u made sure you are in the wright virtual  environment  ? this is definetly looks related to not using the wright env

Comment: @tdelaney When i do just "pip list" in my terminal it shows me a list of packages including websocket-client. However when I copy and past the path that you wrote out, it shows me a completely different list of packages which does not include websocket-client.

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui i believe i am using anaconda, but how do i check to make sure that it is anaconda? Also i only have one venv and in that venv i created a bot.py file for my code. I want to post a screen shot for you to see, but i dont know if stack overflow allows that.

Comment: @It_is_Chris i meant websocket-client, sorry.

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui here is a link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/dYHkoXs

Comment: Yep ..it seems to me you are running the script from the wrong virtual env, here you are in base but in the screenshot your env is called venv .. please make sure you are in the wright virtual environement

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui my bash terminal shows (venv) but my python terminal shows (base). I don't understand why it is doing that? I put my python file in my venv folder like it shows in the screen shot. i used python -m venv venv to create the environment on bash.